# Using rapidjson and assimp together causes rapidjson to behave unpredictably

Tags: c++, assimp, rapidjson

I have the following test program (test.gltf is a file containing just "{}"):

```cpp
#include "assimp/Importer.hpp"
#include "assimp/postprocess.h"
#include "assimp/scene.h"

#include "rapidjson/document.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "reading test" << std::endl;
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile("test.gltf", {});
    std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "testing document" << std::endl;
    rapidjson::Document document;
    std::cout << document.HasMember("product") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get an error on the `ReadFile` call:

```
main: /home/sanderv/dev/twikbot-core/external/assimp/code/../contrib/rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h:1336: rapidjson::GenericValue::MemberIterator rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<>>::FindMember(const GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator> &) [Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>, Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>, SourceAllocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]: Assertion `IsObject()' failed.
```

This is odd because `ReadFile` should work, and just return `nullptr`. When I remove the call to `document.HasMember` in the above program this does work. Stepping through the code shows that something very odd is going on, on stepping into the actual `FindMember` function the `*this` object looks corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

The cause was in the way the program is built, I'm using static libraries. Assimp is built using

```
-DRAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING=1 -DRAPIDJSON_NOMEMBERITERATORCLASS
```

If I compile the above test program with these flags (looks like specifically the last one is needed) then the odd behavior goes away. It had to be something like this of course, my knowledge of compilers and linkers is too limited to know exactly what's wrong, besides that statically linking against basically two slightly different versions of rapidjson is a no-go.

Comment: Strange, do we need to update something in the assimp buildchain?

Comment: @KimKulling I don't know if assimp normally handles this situation well. In my case however the cmake config used to build assimp was unrelated to the one used to build the rest of the project, so I don't think there is anything assimp could have done differently?